# Instability when loading JQuery dynamically in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, window

I have a functionality where depending on the situation I need to declare the library of the JQuery and some others scripts, as the Alert.js script which is a class of the same name. I have tested that functionality in the Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox. At the first the scripts always are loaded correctly before the execution of the class function/class Alert(), however at the Firefox the scripts are loaded astatically, in the other words, when the function Alert are executed, some times the jQuery are not yet ready, being necessary to refresh the page.

To clarify further, the value returned by the Firefox error console is:

```
ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
```

See the code below:

```
if (typeof (Alert) === 'undefined') {

    var scripts = [
        DIR_JS_LIB + 'lib/jquery/jquery.min.js',
        DIR_JS_LIB + 'lib/jquery/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js',
        DIR_JS_LIB + 'scripts/componentes/dialog/AcaoJanela.js',
        DIR_JS_LIB + 'scripts/componentes/dialog/Botao.js',
        DIR_JS_LIB + 'scripts/componentes/dialog/Dialog.js',
        DIR_JS_LIB + 'scripts/componentes/dialog/Alert.js'
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
        include(scripts[i]);
    }

}
window.onload = function () {

    Alert(window.mensagem, window.titulo, window.botoes);
}

function include(file_path) {
    var j = document.createElement("script");
    j.src = file_path;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(j);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuring the cross-browser solution for making the dependant js libraries loaded and ready is well known problem. Your `include` script is not meeting it well. What for me works the best is checking the state of the loaded files, and chaining the calls in the form of callbacks. In your case it would be something like the following:

```
function include(filename, callback) {
    var fileref = document.createElement('script');
    fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
    fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);
    if (fileref.readyState) {
        fileref.onreadystatechange = function () { /*IE*/
            if (fileref.readyState == "loaded" || fileref.readyState == "complete") {
                fileref.onreadystatechange = null;
                callback();
            }
        }
    } else {
        fileref.onload = function () {  /*Other browsers*/
            callback();
        }
    }
    // Try to find the head, otherwise default to the documentElement
    if (typeof fileref != "undefined")
        (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(fileref)
}


if (typeof (Alert) === 'undefined') {

    var scripts = [
            DIR_JS_LIB + 'lib/jquery/jquery.min.js',
            DIR_JS_LIB + 'lib/jquery/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js',
            DIR_JS_LIB + 'scripts/componentes/dialog/AcaoJanela.js',
            DIR_JS_LIB + 'scripts/componentes/dialog/Botao.js',
            DIR_JS_LIB + 'scripts/componentes/dialog/Dialog.js',
            DIR_JS_LIB + 'scripts/componentes/dialog/Alert.js'
    ];

    include(scripts[0], function () {
        include(scripts[1], function () {
            include(scripts[2], function () {
                include(scripts[3], function () {
                    include(scripts[4], function () {
                        include(scripts[5], function () {
                            Alert(window.mensagem, window.titulo, window.botoes);
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });

}
```

Comment: I had tested the code suggested by you, and works perfectly. I didn't think  about callbacks, and that was made the difference. Thank you!